# Video view android and low api levels

Tags: android, api, android-videoview

my video plays on high api level phones its an mp4 format small clip

but not in low ones eg. Samsung duos  api 15 - no error just a black screen in the video view

so i checked my gradle for min sdk and its 11 and max is 23 so it does not make a issue

here is the code

```
private String path ;
    private VideoView mVideoView;
```

in- onCreate

```
path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.nameofvideo;
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.start();
```

xml part for video view

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/myVideo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

how can i play a video on a phone like api 15 or like 13?

Comment: The VideoView itself is rather shaky - Take a look at ExoPlayer by Google for better video player support.  https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html

Answer (score 0):

See if adding the middle line works:

```
   mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
   mVideoView.requestFocus();
   mVideoView.start();
```